# To build a tablet as a final yr project

Tags: 14.04, tablet

as a student of final yr i want to make a tablet of simple specification but i m not getting how to install any OS in it,
I read about Ubuntu OS for tab, can i really install and Ubuntu on tab and if yes HOW???
please answer..

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to run [Ubuntu on Google Nexus tables](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/), have a look at this [list of supported devices](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/).
If you are building your own device from scratch, you can try to port the Nexus image. Goog luck with that.